Как захешировать пароль на c++
Хочу сделать чтобы после регистрации пользователя в базу данных сохранялся захешированный пароль, но не знаю как это сделать и с помощью какой библиотеки. Делаю приложение на qt.

Можно использовать QCryptographicHash:
QByteArray hiddenPassword = QCryptographicHash::hash("password", QCryptographicHash::Md5);


Следует обратить внимание, что MD5 это не криптографически устойчивый хэш и для паролей вообще говоря не подходит

@BeardedBeaver, лично вы видели много взломанных MD5?

@avp на ныне умершем hashes.org таких наверняка было навалом

@andreymal, и все они прямой перебор для фраз короче десятка символов? Не слышал о действительно быстром алгоритме для поиска коллизий MD5

@avp а быстрый и не надо, если есть тысячи добровольцев с видеокартами)

@andreymal, добавьте соль из 30 байт и посчитайте сколько лет понадобиться вообще всем видеокартам (пусть даже она считает 10 ** 12 хэшей в секунду (реально большинство  из них так не сможет))

@avp поскольку соль обычно хранится в открытом виде рядом с хэшем - столько же, сколько и без соли

Это дискуссия, не имеющая отношения к вопросу, но соль не про усложнение подбора конкретного пароля. Соль про то, что хорошие криптографические хеши считать долго, и проще посчитать один хэш одного пароля и сравнить его со всеми хешами в базе, глядишь какой подойдет. Соль делает все хэши уникальными и придется для каждой комбинации считать заново.

@andreymal, ну, вы поняли. Речь идет просто не о слишком коротком пароле (думаю, 12 байт уже не ломается за разумное время)

@avp а теперь попробуйте найти людей с 12-байтовыми паролями, я своих знакомых и на 10 символов заставил перейти с трудом, а у некоторых до сих пор и 8 встречается)

@andreymal, всего 6 русских букв в utf-8 (хотя мне ближе позиция RMS в молодости (что они вообще не нужны))

@avp а теперь попробуйте найти людей с русскими буквами в паролях, да что там — хотя бы сайт позволяющий пихать русские буквы в пароль) Мне тут недавно один супербезопасный банк запретил использовать точку в пароле, какие блин ещё русские буквы)

@avp а вообще для справки, RTX 4090 подберёт 12-символьный пароль (с английскими буквами, цифрами и спецсимволами) за 100 тысяч лет. Если собрать все RTX 4090, выпущенные за первый месяц, вместе (поблизости к какой-нибудь АЭС), то хватит и года

@andreymal, хорошо. Кстати, я не сомневаюсь, что в ФСБ (той части, что ранее была ФАПСИ) и NSA есть аппаратура, которая работает еще шустрей. Только вот мои (и ваши тоже) пароли таким серьезным людям совсем не нужны. Да и любым серьезным людям пароли ни к чему. Был бы человек живой (вот с мертвецами сложней, их уже не спросишь...)

Алгоритм шифрования можно выбрать другой (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html#Algorithm-enum)

@e.n.shirokov и среди них ни одного подходящего для паролей

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessageauthenticationcode.html наверное лучше
